# Problem in Android activity: ListView shows no items, even in minimum implementation

Tags: java, android, listview

the following code does not work as desired.

Does anyone here has a hint?

Thank you in advance,

Sven

Already played around by putting this in onCreate, by making listView, strings, arrayAdapter instance fields and so one. Did not helped.

Making it final or not did not helped.

Changing the length and/or/xor the array's content did not helped.

Activity class:

```
    ...

    ListView listView = this.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    final int n = 10;
    String[] strings = new String[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        strings[i] = "X" + i;
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);

    Log.d(this, "#1 " + arrayAdapter.getCount());

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    Log.d(this, "#2 " + listView.getChildCount());

    ...
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    tools:context=".AndroidMainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.9">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1.0">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".33"
                    android:background="#007f00"
                    android:onClick="onClickStart"
                    android:text="@string/log_start" />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".34"
                    android:background="#00007f"
                    android:onClick="onClickMark"
                    android:text="@string/mark" />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".33"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:background="#7f0000"
                    android:onClick="onClickStop"
                    android:text="@string/log_stop" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Instead of showing a list with 10 items, nothing is shown. Debug shows "#1 10" for first and "#2 0" for second statement. I've copied this 1:1 from another well working project incl. the layout XML.

Comment: But we don't know the full layout so we can't know if the views around it are misconfigured.

Comment: Ah, okay, here we go: